# Isn't requiescat actually subjunctive?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

St Augustine wrote:

“Fecisti nos ad te, Domine, et inquietum est cor nostrum donec requiescat in te” (“You made us for you, Lord, and our heart is restless until it reposes in you” – “Confessions,” 1.1.1.)

https://sixtogarcia.wordpress.com/2016/08/25/st-augustine-give-me-a-loving-heart/

When I look up requiescat it is said to be subjunctive.
This has always been how I have used it in eg requiescat in pace ((may he/she) rest in peace).

Does this mean that the translation above is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

No, because *donec* meaning 'until' may take the subjunctive. Compare eg. French *jusqu'à ce qu'il vienne* 'until he comes (subj.)'. The logic is that an event that one wishes or expects to occur is not a certain fact, hence the subjunctive mood.